# getElementByClassName + classList.add não funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou usando bootstrap para um trabalho, tenho uma classe que se repete v'arias vezes, gostaria de usar o getElementByClassName para pegar todos os elementos que tem essa classe e usar o clasList.add para adicionar mais uma classe, mudando a classe de todos os objetos.

```
<div class="conteiner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="border"> <!-- div que quero adicionar a classe -->
        <h1>Ola Mundo</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<script>
    const elemento = document.getElementByClassName('border');
var renovavel = false;
  if (renovavel === true) {
    elemento.classList.add('border-dark');
  }
  else {
    elemento.classList.add('border-success');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

"getElementByClassName" não existe, tem `getElementsByClassName` que retorna um array de elementos, por isso precisa iterar sobre esses elementos, usando `for` ou `foreach` por exemplo.

Adicionei um exemplo com `getElementsByClassName`e também demonstrando `querySelector` e `querySelectorAll`

```js
// getElementsByClassName pega todos elmentos:
const elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('border');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementos, function(elemento) {
       elemento.classList.add('border-dark');
});

// querySelector pega só o primeiro
var elementosDiferente = document.querySelector(".border-diferente");
elementosDiferente.classList.add('border-red');


// querySelectorAll pega todos elementos:
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.teste');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(elemento) {
       elemento.classList.add('fundo');
});
```

```css
.border-dark {
  border: solid 3px #000
 }
 
 .border-red {
  border: solid 3px red
 }
 
 .fundo {
    background-color: cyan
 }
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="teste border">
        <h1>Ola Mundo 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="teste border-diferente">
        <h1>Ola Mundo 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="teste border">
        <h1>Ola Mundo 3</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="teste border-diferente">
        <h1>Ola Mundo 4</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Mais detalhes na documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName